# Problema mostrando imagen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un fragmento de código que utliza Boostrap 4 y alguna personalización con CSS, funciona bien, pero cuando intento agregar un carusel para no mostrar una sola imagen me falla, pues la imagen no se muestra completa, se muestra solo una parte de ella y con apariencia de zoom.

Código que funciona bien:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="property shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
<a href="#" class="property-img">
<div class="img-fade"></div>
<div class="property-tag badge badge-success"><h5>Nuevo</h5></div>
<div class="property-price">$150,000</div>
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/906_28355846338_3e54c3bd3f_320_240_nofilter.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<div class="property-content">
<div class="property-title">
<h4><a href="#">Modern Family Home</a></h4>
<p class="property-address"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> 123 Smith Dr, Annapolis, MD</p>
</div>
<table class="property-details">
<tbody><tr>
<td><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> 3 Hab.</td>
<td><i class="fa fa-tint"></i> 2 Baños</td>
<td><i class="fa fa-expand"></i> 105 m2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
<div class="property-footer">
<span class="left"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o icon"></i> 5 days ago</span>
<span class="right">
<a href="#"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Código con el carusel que da el problema:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="property shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">   
<a href="#" class="property-img">
<div class="img-fade"></div>
<div class="property-tag badge badge-success"><h5>Nuevo</h5></div>
<div class="property-price">$150,000</div>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img class="image-fluid" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/realestate/all" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/906_28355846338_3e54c3bd3f_320_240_nofilter.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/realestate/" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>

<p class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</p>
<p class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</p>
</div>
</a>

<div class="property-content">
<div class="property-title">
<h4><a href="#">Modern Family Home</a></h4>
<p class="property-address"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> 123 Smith Dr, Annapolis, MD</p>
</div>
<table class="property-details">
<tbody><tr>
<td><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> 3 Hab.</td>
<td><i class="fa fa-tint"></i> 2 Baños</td>
<td><i class="fa fa-expand"></i> 105 m2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
<div class="property-footer">
<span class="left"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o icon"></i> 5 days ago</span>
<span class="right">
<a href="#"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Todo se encuentra dentro de un DIV con la clase Row:

```
<div class="row">
```

Comment: Tienes el código de css que estas usando para agregarlo en la pregunta, la prueba con solo el HTML se ve bien!!

Comment: hice un cambio en el CSS y funcionó, muchas gracias!